# Laravel + Vue spa two step router not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

Laravel: 7.17, Vue: 2.5.17.

I made simple sidebar and tried to work that.

One step router ( /admin, /home, /... ) worked well but two steps router(/admin/blog/category, /admin/blog/post...) didn't work.

Here is what I did.

-routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function() {
   return view('app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

-resources/views/app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="app">
           <div class="container mx-auto">
               <main class="d-flex">
                   <aside class="w-25">
                        <section>
                            <ul>
                                <li><router-link to="/admin">Dashboard</router-link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>
                       <section>
                           <h6>Blog </h6>
                           <ul class="list-group">
                               <li><router-link to="/admin/blog/category">Category</router-link></li>
                               <li><router-link to="/admin/blog/post">Posts</router-link></li>
                           </ul>
                       </section>
                   </aside>
                   <div class="p-3">

                        <router-view></router-view>
                        
                   </div>
               </main>
           </div>
       </div>

       <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

-resources/js/app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',


    router: new VueRouter(routes)
});
```

-resources/js/routes.js

```
import Home from './components/Home';
import Admin from './components/admin/Admin';
import Category from './components/admin/blog/Category';
import Post from './components/admin/blog/Post';
import PathThrough from './components/PathThrough';

export default {
    mode:'history',

    routes:[
        {
            path:'/',
            component: Home
        },

        {
            path:'/admin',component: Admin,
            children: [
                {
                    path:'blog', component: PathThrough,
                    children: [
                        { path: 'category', component: Category},
                        { path: 'post', component: Post},
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },


    ]

};
```

-resources/js/components/PathThrough.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
    <script>
    export default {};
</script>
```

-other components

```
<template>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {};
</script>
```

Here, /admin and / routes are working.
But other routes don't work.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: do put router-view in Admin and PathThrough components?

Comment: How? I put those but still not working? Could you please put some code here?

Comment: look for detecting its the backend issue or frontend easy. if you can enter route but when you refresh got an error its backend issue but for e.x. you're in home page but cant enter other router its frontend issue. so which one is it?

Comment: Well, no error. It works well same in any case. But instead of blog post and category page, it shows just admin page.